# Possible to attach Elastic IP to sagemaker notebook instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I want to connect to a database running in different cloud provider and it is exposed publicly.

I need to connect to that database from sagemaker notebook instance.

But the public ip of the sagemaker notebook instance needs to be whitelisted on the other side.

Is it possible to attach elastic ip to sagemaker notebook instance as I don't see any option to attach eip to sagemaker notebook instance?

Comment: This question is deduped from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=926299 .

Comment: @NeelamGehlot I don't think Amazon forums constitutes a dupe, but a citable answer, which I have created below.

Answer (score 2):

*No, it is not possible to assign a SageMaker notebook an Elastic IP*, which is a disappointment. This missing feature makes the SageMaker product a lot more difficult to use with many sources of data, limiting its utility.

### Official Amazon Answer

From the AWS SageMaker product forums on Dec 12, 2019: [Possible to attach Elastic IP to sagemaker notebook instance?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=926299)

```
Question> Is it possible to attach elastic ip to sagemaker notebook instance?

Answer> We are always re-evaluating our backlog of features based on customer requests,
so we appreciate the feedback on this feature.
```

You might want to start a new thread or chime in on that one if you want them to add this feature.

### Possible Solutions

A general strategy for using a particular IP to access a resource would be to setup a proxy machine and authorize its IP and use it as a proxy to access your service. How hard this is depends on what you are doing - for S3 it doesn't seem possible - but for web-based requests this shouldn't be too hard. For AWS services you can [use a proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/sending-requests-through-a-proxy/).

Personally I am trying to access Algoseek's requestor-pays S3 buckets directly from SageMaker notebooks and this isn't possible. I looked at setting up a proxy but can't figure out how. Instead I will copy the S3 data each time they add a day into our own S3 bucket.

Comment: FYI, I am same person posted the question in stackoverflow and in AWS Forum :)

Comment: @karthikeayan Ah, you have the honor of being cited in an answer to your own question. There must be a badge for that? :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have whitelisted the NAT Gateway's IP in the external database.

EDIT: This works only for private subnets.

Comment: This is only a temporary fix. As soon as the notebook instace is shut down and started again it will receive a fresh IP from the AWS pool which means you have to go back and whitelist that new IP again...

Comment: Only Public IP associated with the notebook instance will get refreshed. NAT Gateway's IP will not. I updated my answer.